# amcl demo: map_server could not open yaml file (yaml file exists)

Tags: navigation, mapping, turtlebot, map-server, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**tl;dr**
I am trying to open amcl demo with:

```
 roslaunch chefbot_gazebo amcl_demo.launch map_file:=home/neuronet/hotel_world.yaml
```

And I am getting error:

```
Map_server could not open home/neuronet/hotel_world.yaml
```

**Long version**
I'm in indigo, ros version 1.11.20 on Ubuntu 14, and I am working through a project (chefbot) that is based on turtlebot:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Chefbot-A-DIY-Autonomous-mobile-robot-for-serving-/?ALLSTEPS#step2

I have run the gmapping_demo and created a map, and saved the map using

```
rosrun map_server map_saver -f ~/hotel_world
```

This has saved hotel_world.yaml and hotel_world.pgm in my home directory. Then the goal is to run the amcl demo. First (as instructed at instructables) I open the robot in gazebo, which works:

```
roslaunch chefbot_gazebo chefbot_hotel_world.launch
```

And then I launch the amcl_demo:

```
roslaunch chefbot_gazebo amcl_demo.launch map_file:=home/neuronet/hotel_world.yaml
```

It seems to start working (nodes start) but eventually I get the error that the map server could not open the yaml file:

```
core service [/rosout] found
process[map_server-1]: started with pid [6488]
process[amcl-2]: started with pid [6489]
process[move_base-3]: started with pid [6491]
**[ERROR] [1471437118.250759705]: Map_server could not open home/neuronet/hotel_world.yaml.**
```

Strangely, the. yaml file does exist in the intended directory. Here are the yaml file contents:

> image: /home/neuronet/hotel_world.pgm
> resolution: 0.010000 origin:
> [-11.240000, -12.200000, 0.000000]
> negate: 0 occupied_thresh: 0.65
> free_thresh: 0.196

Further, the pgm file (image) does exist, here it is:
[image: image description]

Note I'm working with rospy, if that matters (any technical c++ stuff will likely go over my head).

Finally, here is the file amcl_demo.launch file:

```
<launch>
  <!-- Map server -->
  <arg name="map_file" default="$(find chefbot_gazebo)/maps/playground.yaml"/>

  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)" />

  <!-- Localization -->
  <arg name="initial_pose_x" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_y" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_a" default="0.0"/>
  <include file="$(find chefbot_bringup)/launch/includes/amcl.launch.xml">
    <arg name="initial_pose_x" value="$(arg initial_pose_x)"/>
    <arg name="initial_pose_y" value="$(arg initial_pose_y)"/>
    <arg name="initial_pose_a" value="$(arg initial_pose_a)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- Move base -->
  <include file="$(find chefbot_bringup)/launch/includes/move_base.launch.xml"/>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241870/amcl-demo:-map_server-could-not-open-yaml-file-(yaml-file-exists)/) by [neuronet](https://answers.ros.org/users/27484/neuronet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2016-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you are missing a `/` before `home`, it should probably be:

```
roslaunch chefbot_gazebo amcl_demo.launch map_file:=/home/neuronet/hotel_world.yaml
```

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [neuronet](https://answers.ros.org/users/27484/neuronet/) on 2016-08-18**:
Dear me I am such a noob not just to Ros but to *Nix. Thank goodness that I just halted design for 36 hours because of this mistake I am super efficient! On the plus side, I will not make this mistake again. :)

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-08-18**:
I guess everybody here stumbled upon this one at least once ;-)